# lexicon file into dict python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, sentiment-analysis

So we were presented with a problem where given a lexicon of positive and negative words in a txt format, we had to transfer that into a dictionary({}), and I was just wondering if there are better ways to do this other than copying all the words and positive and negative numbers into the list. like using a for loop. Thank you!
the data were presented to us like this in a txt file

```
tasty 2.52
gracious 2.52
joyful 2.64
```

what we have to do is print this out in a dict

```
#modified by: Ou Li
#date: 2/24/2018
import sys
def main():
    filename = sys.argv[-1]
    print_lexicon(filename)
def print_lexicon(filename):
    lexicon = {}
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            key,value = line.strip().split(',')
            lexicon = {key:value}
    print (lexicon)
```

This is what I have right now

Answer (score 0):

If your words don't have any spaces, or you can change the separator value between word and value to something unique, you can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html). Example script:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(r"test.txt", sep=' ', header=None, names=['Word', 'Value'])
print(df.head())

# returns: 
#
#    Word       Value
# 0  tasty      2.52
# 1  gracious   2.52
# 2  joyful     2.64
```

Then if you need the values to pass to something else, `df.values` returns a numpy array of the values:

```
print(df.values)

# returns:
#
# [['tasty', 2.52]
#  ['gracious', 2.52]
#  ['joyful', 2.64]]
```

edit:
Since you can't use pandas, just open the file and iterate through the lines directly. You'll have to implement error catching as needed, but here's a simple example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

{word: value for word, value in [line.rstrip('\n').split(' ') for line in contents]}
```

Comment: thank you, could this be done with a python diction {}

Comment: What do you mean? If you just want a dict like `{'tasty': 2.52'}` this one-liner will work: `{word: value for word, value in df.values}`. Note it will only keep one value if you have more than one instance of a word

Comment: we are not allowed to use df

Comment: where exactly are you stuck then? What have you tried out?

Comment: I don't really understand how I can have the words and values go separately into the dict.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but you must execute the `main` function and adjust the way that you add to the dictionary. The way that you are doing it at the moment will create a single entry for each item in the file, leaving you with only the last item.

```
import sys
def main():
    filename = sys.argv[-1]
    print_lexicon(filename)

def print_lexicon(filename):
    lexicon = {}
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            key,value = line.strip().split(',')
            lexicon[key]=value
    print (lexicon)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Input:

```
tasty, 2.52
gracious, 2.52
joyful, 2.64
```

Output:

```
{'tasty': ' 2.52', 'joyful': ' 2.64', 'gracious': ' 2.52'}
```

If you need the `value` to be numeric, change the above to:

```
lexicon[key]=float(value)
```